# How do I set up sshd using Cygwin on Windows 7 for remote login

Tags: windows-7, ssh, cygwin, zsh, sshd

I'd like to set up an ssh server with Cygwin on my Windows 7 desktop so that I can remotely access my computer in a more civilized way than using VNC.  I would like to use `zsh` as my default shell.  I would like to be able to use an existing keypair in both directions (i.e. remotely accessing the desktop and logging into other machines from the desktop). I would love to set this up once and never mess with it again.

Here's what I have so far:

- Cygwin is installed with every possible package (I didn't realize at the time what I was getting into, but it's done)
- I have run `ssh-host-config` based on one or more online guides.
- I have changed my shell to `zsh`.
- I have added various things to my `.zshrc` which are designed to launch `ssh-agent` on shell login, but they all leave multiple `ssh-agent` processes running after the shell is closed (I assume this is bad)
- I would rather just have a "global" `ssh-agent` running
- At one point, I was able to make outgoing ssh connections to other machines (incoming connections timed out), but this doesn't work anymore.

I would really love to know how to get sshd to start on startup (of my computer so I don't need to leave a terminal open), and how to get `ssh-agent` to start once and stay started so I don't need to type my key's passphrase all the time.

I have access to my router (for port forwarding).

I am not a shell configuration wizard (i.e. I don't know enough to write something to launch ssh-agent properly).

How do I coax cygwin and `sshd` into meeting my needs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just install a ssh server for windows? Like [Freesshd](http://www.freesshd.com/). Making it work through cygwin just seem like an unnecessary complication.

Comment: I'd really like having zsh on the other end of the connection.  It's nice to have a *nix-style terminal with most or all of the associated commands.

Comment: well, if you put `path/to/cygwin/bin` in your path, you can just ssh and type `zsh`

Comment: I figured it would be better to have it all run through the same system rather than having different components talk to each other.  I'll do freesshd for now, until somebody comes up with a better plan.